# ASP.NET alert newline from CodeBehind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, newline, alert

I have such code in Page.aspx.cs file:

```
void btnSessionCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (Session["user"] == null)
        {
            Session["user"] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            Response.Redirect("/");
        }
        else if (Session["user"] != null)
        {
            string userBrowser = Request.UserAgent.ToString();
            string sessionId = Session["user"].ToString();

            Response.Write("<script>alert('" + sessionId + "\r\n" + userBrowser + "');</script>");
        }
 }
```

The main problem is "\r\n" part in Response.Write() method. I wanted to separate data with a newline, but can't!

If there is not "\r\n" , script alerts well, but if exists in code nothing is alerting and  is changing resets its CSS style.

Why?

Comment: You SHOULD NOT be using response.write to output JavaScript. Bad design. Look at `RegisterStartupscript`!

Comment: @epascarello Why shouldn't I to use it?

Comment: Response.Write can screw up the stream and it is not dependable when it will be sent. Use the methods built into the code to register JavaScript.

Comment: @epascarello and how can I then call the registered script from the CodeBehind? And also, I don't want to register it StartUp? Doesn't exist just `Regsiter` without StartUp extension? Thanks!

Comment: Read the docs on it, it explains it with examples.

Comment: @epascarello as on: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=274 Master.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript() also is used for calling???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `@` symbol or double `\\` to escape the slash

```
string script = String.Format(@"<script>alert('{0}\r\n{1}');</script>", sessionId, userBrowser);
```

OR

```
string script = String.Format("<script>alert('{0}\\r\\n{1}');</script>", sessionId, userBrowser);

Client.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myscript", script, true);
```

[More info on Client.RegisterStartupScript here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx)

Comment: thank you for a good answer, another little question I have for you about RegisterScript method. If I register it, how can I call then it from any place on CodeBehind exactly? Thank you!

Comment: You can call it anywhere - button_click, page_load, etc. It inserts a javascript snippet into your page and it takes effect immediately after your page is loaded/reloaded. Any function declared in such script should be available to your page. Just give it a try and see how it works.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to escape the `\`, so they become `\` when output to JavaScript:

```
Response.Write("<script>alert('" + sessionId + "\\r\\n" + userBrowser + "');</script>");
```

Or:

```
Response.Write("<script>alert('" + sessionId + @"\r\n" + userBrowser + "');</script>");
```

You are in a C# context in the above line, so `\r\n` is interpreted as a new line that needs to be output by `Response.Write`. that's not what you want. You want the literal `\r\n` to be output, so they are interpreted as JavaScript newlines.

Answer (score 0):

Response.Write("alert('" + sessionId + "\n" + userBrowser + "');");

this will work fine in asp.net